# Enable/Disable specific buttons in a ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to enable the save button in a specific row and disable two buttons (add Selector and add Section) in a loop above through the edit button. But i am not able to disable/enable just a specific button that got generated. 
Also i would like to manage it in my component to Enable/Disable.
I hope anyone can help me.

My Form Looks like this -> https://gyazo.com/329e442becd93222d33c15b1232cc9d2

```
<div formArrayName="sectionList">
    <div *ngFor="let section of myForm.get('sectionList').controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <div formGroupName="section">
        <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="enableSection(i)">Edit</button>    
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="name" formControlName="name">
          <mat-error *ngIf=""> 
              todo
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>   
        <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="deleteSection(i)" >Delete</button>    
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="true" (click)="saveSection(i)">Save</button> 
      </div>

      <div formArrayName="selectorList">
        <div *ngFor="let selector of section.controls.selectorList.controls; let j=index" [formGroupName]="j">
          <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="enableSelector(i, j)">Edit</button>    
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="locator" formControlName="locator" >
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="language" formControlName="language" >
          </mat-form-field>            
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="value" formControlName="value" >
          </mat-form-field> 
          <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="deleteSelector(i,j)">Delete</button> 
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="isDisabled" (click)="saveSelector(i,j)">Save</button>   
        </div>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="addSelector(i)">Add Selector</button>    
      </div>    
    </div> 
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="addSection()">Add Section</button>     
  </div>
```

```
 enableSection(i){
    this.sectionForms.controls[i].get('section').enable();
  }

  enableSelector(i, j){
    this.isDisabled = false;
    this.myForm.get('sectionList.' + i + '.selectorList.' + j).enable();
  }
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: i dont get an error, i just dont know how to disable/enable specific buttons.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add to the button you wanna disable `[disabled]="rowIWannaDisable === i"` where `i` is the index of the `*ngFor` like in `ngFor="let section of myForm.get('sectionList').controls; let i=index"` and `rowIWannaDisable` is the row number where you want the button disabled. You could also use a function instead of `rowIWannaDisable` to select the disabled row dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @alexortizl . I tried this:  `<button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="sectionI === i && selectorJ === j"  (click)="saveSelector(i,j)">Save</button>` and if i press edit it sets the button to "disabled". But i need to initial disable all save buttons and then enable one save btn with the edit btn. Do you have any ideas? sadly i didnt find a [enabled] attribute and i just need the opposite effect.

Comment: buttons are enabled by default. If the condition given to the `[disabled]` attribute is true then the button will be disabled if it is false it will be enabled that's why there isn't a `enabled` attribute. For example in you comment above when `sectionI === i && selectorJ === j` returns true the button will be disabled if it returns false the button will be enabled. The solution here would be to implement a logic that matches your requirements in the disabled attribute.